# EnterCriticalSection doesn't lock

Tags: c++, windows

This is a small part of my code:

```
CRITICAL_SECTION _cs;
InitializeCriticalSection(&_cs);

 void lock() {
    if (_initizalized){
      EnterCriticalSection(&_cs);
      EnterCriticalSection(&_cs);
      _locked = true;
    }
  }
```

(I wrote "EnterCriticalSection" twice , because I noticed that this line doesn't work)
As I understand, this must cause a deadlock. but it doesn't. why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No the same thread can enter it as often as it wants.
CRITICAL_SECTION is used to restrict access between multiple different threads.

Answer (score 7):

[EnterCriticalSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682608%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) allows for recursive calls from the same thread.  From the documentation:

> After a thread has ownership of a critical section, it can make
>   additional calls to EnterCriticalSection or TryEnterCriticalSection
>   without blocking its execution. This prevents a thread from
>   deadlocking itself while waiting for a critical section that it
>   already owns. The thread enters the critical section each time
>   EnterCriticalSection and TryEnterCriticalSection succeed. A thread
>   must call LeaveCriticalSection once for each time that it entered the
>   critical section.

Answer (score 3):

As [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682608%28v=vs.85%29.aspx),

After a thread has ownership of a critical section, **it can make additional calls to EnterCriticalSection or TryEnterCriticalSection without blocking its execution**. This prevents a thread from deadlocking itself while waiting for a critical section that it already owns. The thread enters the critical section each time EnterCriticalSection and TryEnterCriticalSection succeed. A thread must call LeaveCriticalSection once for each time that it entered the critical section.